# Haskell Recursion using an Accumulator

Tags: function, haskell, recursion, accumulator

I'm trying to make a function that will look for 3 identical and adjacent numbers given a list, for a solver I am trying to implement. Then, if there are 3 identical and adjacent numbers, it will mark the 1st and 3rd identical numbers to '0' and set the middle value to be negative.

I am wondering why this is giving me an error.:

```
change xs = chnge xs []
    where
    chnge xs acc
        | length xs <= 2 = [acc]
        | (head xs == xs !! 1) && (head xs == xs !! 2) = [0, (xs !! 1)*(-1), 0] ++ tail xs
        | otherwise = chnge (tail xs) (acc ++ head xs)
```

Comment: This is simply a parse error because your where clause (as well as its content) should be indented by at least one space compared to the clause defining `change`. As a general rule, you should include in your question the error message that GHC gives you.

Comment: Sorry, that was my mistake. I simply forgot to indent the rest of the code. I have fixed it to match what it really is.

Comment: The parse error is due to stackoverflow messing up formatting, not the original source.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since `acc` is a list, we don't want to return `[acc]` in the first guard of `chnge`, but just `acc`; similarly in the `otherwise` line you don't want `acc ++ head xs` which would mean that `xs` is a list of lists -- how else could its first member be appendable? Rather `acc ++ [head xs]` So maybe:

```
change xs = chnge xs [] where
  chnge xs acc
        | length xs <= 2 = acc
        | (head xs == xs !! 1) && (head xs == xs !! 2) = [0, (xs !! 1)*(-1), 0] ++ tail xs
        | otherwise = chnge (tail xs) (acc ++ [head xs])
```

This seems a little off, but the real problem is the dearth of 'pattern matching' and the dangerous use of `head`,`tail` and `!!`. Try something more like this, maybe? (It doesn't use an accumulator though):

```
change []     = []
change [x]    = [x]
change [x,y]  = [x,y]
change (x:y:z:ws) | x == y && y == z = 0 : (-y) : 0 : change ws
change (x:xs) =  x : change xs

--  *Main> change [12,12,66,66,66,44,44,99,99,99,76,1]
--  [12,12,0,-66,0,44,44,0,-99,0,76,1]
```

The case of three in a row can be considered as a pattern, so that we make a special case for when they're equal.